# File upload using Django Forms

Tags: python, django

I have a file field in MissFormModel model:

`file                = models.FileField(upload_to ='uploads/')`

My index view display all MissFormModel instances:

```
def index(request):
context ={}

forms = MissFormModel.objects.all()

if forms.exists():
    return render(request, 'app/index.html', {'forms':forms,'context':context})
else:
    return render(request, 'app/index.html', {'forms':None,'context':context})
```

My index template:

```
{% for i in forms %}

<tr>
  <th scope="row">{{i.id}}</th>
  <th>{{i.sender}}</th>
    <th>
        {% if i.file %}
            <a href="{{ i.file.url }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" target="_blank">
          Download
        </a>
        {% endif %}
        
    </th>
</tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

Now I am trying to implement file upload forms.

My forms.py looks like:

```
class SendNewRequest(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = MissFormModel
    fields = ("sender", "file")
    labels = {
        'sender':'',
        'file':'',
        }
    widgets = {}
```

My view to file upload:

```
def send_new_request(request):
form = SendNewRequest()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SendNewRequest(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('index')

return render(request, 'forms/new_request.html', {'form':form})
```

My new_request.html:

```
<form action="" method="POST" encytpe="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <button type="submit">Save</button>
            </form>
```

But when I've created new forms with attachment at my index page i see nothing. The same situation in admin page. Could you explain what i am doing wrong?

Comment: There are no `forms`, only a *single* `form`...?

Comment: I've forgot to add my index view to this question

Answer (score 1):

try this

You have intialzied the empty form and then you are trying to save it.

```
def send_new_request(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SendNewRequest(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')
    form = SendNewRequest()
    
    return render(request, 'forms/new_request.html', {'form':form})
```